# Projectors and Hermitian Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

Suppose that $|a\rangle$ is a vector in Hilbert space *H*.
Is the projector $|a\rangle\langle a|$ "always" an operator on *H*?

Also, what is the condition under which $|a\rangle\langle a|$ is a Hermitian operator?

Comment: $|a\rangle$ must be of unit norm obviously...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is always an operator. The inner product is defined for all vectors in a space, so $|a\rangle\langle a|\psi\rangle$ is always well-defined. It is also always Hermitian, since its eigenvalues are only $\langle a|a\rangle$ and $0$. If $|a\rangle\langle a|\psi\rangle=c|\psi\rangle$, then we must have $|\psi\rangle=|a\rangle$ or $c=\langle a|\psi\rangle=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  For any vector $\psi$ in the Hilbert space, the projector $P_\psi$, which eats a vector $\phi$ and spits out $\langle\psi,\phi\rangle \psi$, is bounded (with operator norm $\Vert P_\psi \Vert_{op} = \Vert \psi \Vert$, a simple exercise), which means that it can act on the entire Hilbert space.

Furthermore, any such projector can be shown to be Hermitian (and therefore self-adjoint, since it is bounded) by one or two lines of direct computation.